# Inplace array change

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to inplace adjust my array. But seems it does not work. Values remain the same after I run the function on the array.

```
void filter_scan(std::array<float, 270>& scan){
  for(float val : scan){
    if(val < 0.5 || val > 2)
      val = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are passing the array by reference you are accessing each element by value(copy).

```
for(float val : scan)
```

Copies each element of the array into `val` and any modification you do to it will not show in the array.  You need to make `val` a reference like

```
for(float& val : scan)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the array entries *by value*. A local copy `val` is created for every entry, then changed, only to be forgotten again. To obtain a "read-write" type of access, you can scan the array *by reference* instead:

```
void filter_scan(std::array<float, 270>& scan){
  for(float& val : scan) { // Notice the "&"!
    if(val < 0.5 || val > 2)
      val = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference:

```
void filter_scan(std::array<float, 270>& scan){
  for(float &val : scan){
    if(val < 0.5 || val > 2)
      val = 0;
  }
}
```